# How should I phrase this / where can I ask this?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/332180/linux-vs-code-vs-windows-visual-studio-tradeoffs

I'm guessing Quora? If my questions aren't welcome here I'm more than happy to move away from StackExchange as it's becoming more and more frustrating to discern what questions are valid where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular question isn't a good fit anywhere in the Q&A portion of any Stack Exchange site, but there may be a good chat room to ask it in. Every site on the SE network has a Help Center page about [what not to ask](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) that (almost?) "you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". There are a few problems with questions about trade-offs: it's hard for an individual to write a comprehensive and complete answer, many answers could be valid (each presenting a different subset of trade-offs), and there's no problem to solve.

However, your question is still salvageable (since it does not have any answers that would be invalidated by an edit), perhaps even in a way that doesn't need the question to be migrated. If you can focus your question on something that is on-topic here (such as [methods and processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process), or [build management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build), or [deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment)), you can make the changes and then flag it for review.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me.

Comment: I think it is very optimistic that this question can be salvaged - the OP has probably to transform it into a **very** different question.